# facebook login window is not populating when we click on facebook 'like' button in selenium webdrvier

Tags: java, javascript, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi please provide me the solutions for below hmtl sippnet where i need to click on facebook icon and popup window will open but when clicked using selenium click action is not displaying any error but popup window is not appearing.

please give me solution if you come have any.

```
Html tag is as below:

<span style="height: 20px; width: 78px;">
<iframe id="f3117c4afe0839e" class="fb_ltr" scrolling="no" name="feea6afdd270a" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 20px; width: 78px;" title="Like this content on Facebook." src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D29%23cb%3Df1bb10fdb4eaa3c%26domain%3D%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fts.co.uk%252Ff3d88d5ccc0f77a%26relation%3Dparent.parent&colorscheme=light&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Freasion.ui.co.uk%2Fbeauty%2Funlimited-chocolate-fondue-for-2%2F&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=false&width=90">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="facebook" class="" lang="en">
<head>
<body class="plugin gecko win Locale_en_US">
<div class="_li">
<div class="pluginSkinLight pluginFontHelvetica">
<div>
<table id="u_0_0" class="uiGrid _51mz pluginConnectButtonLayoutRoot" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="_51mx">
<td class="_51m- hCent">
<div>
<form id="u_0_1" onsubmit="return window.Event && Event.__inlineSubmit && Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)" action="/plugins/like/connect" method="post" ajaxify="/plugins/like/connect" rel="async">
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="AVp6Zwfv" name="lsd">
<input type="hidden" value="http://reasons.ui.co.uk/beauty/unlimited-chocolate-fondue-for-2/" name="href" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="like" name="action" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="nobootload" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="http://reasons.ui.co.uk/" name="iframe_referer" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="ref" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="xfbml" autocomplete="off">
<div class="pluginConnectButton">
<div class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginButtonInline pluginConnectButtonDisconnected" title="Like">
<div>
<div class="pluginButtonContainer">
<div class="pluginButtonImage">
<button type="submit">
<i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like-blue sx_like-blue_favblue"></i>
</button>
</div>
<span class="pluginButtonLabel">Like</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u show us the code u have tried...it's very vague to help

Comment: String s1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget']//iframe")).getAttribute("id");
      driver.switchTo().frame(s1);
      System.out.println("Switched to "+s1);
      Thread.sleep(5000);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u_0_1']/div/div[1]"));   This is clicking on Like button, but new pop up window is not populating

Comment: I tried with below code also  String s1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget']//iframe")).getAttribute("id");
      driver.switchTo().frame(s1);
      System.out.println("Switched to "+s1);
      Thread.sleep(5000);                                      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         stringBuilder.append("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();");
         js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());

Comment: If i use above java script code then like button is disappearing after clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? If it is FF, you solve this by setting capability. Try following:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
firefoxProfile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.QueryInterface", "allAccess");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.frameElement.get", "allAccess");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```